# Background queue to get a JSON array from web server to iOS

Tags: php, ios

I am executing a background queue to get a value from a MySQL table on a web server.
This is the PHP code I am using to obtain the JSON array :

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$arr = array();

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbcoordenadas where titulo='$id'");
while ($obj = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
$arr[] = $obj['procedencia'];
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

And this is the code for the iOS part to get the JSON array from the internet:

```
   - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
    {
        NSLog(@"annotation taped TITLE %@",[[view annotation] title  ]      ) ;



        //URL definition where php file is hosted
        dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myqueue", 0);

        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{


            NSMutableString *ms = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://mujercanariasigloxxi.appgestion.eu/app_php_files/comprobartipo.php?id="];
            // URL request
            NSString *tipo=[[view annotation] title];

            [ms appendString:tipo];
            NSLog(@"TIPO ES AQUI %@", tipo);
            NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ms]];
            //URL connection to the internet
            //  NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request1
                                               queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                   completionHandler:
             ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data1, NSError *connectionError)
             {
                 if (data1)
                 {
                     NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:0 error:nil];

                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                    {
                                        // Update your label

                                        NSLog(@"PROCEDENCIA DESDE INTERNET %@", [array objectAtIndex:0]);

                                    });
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     // Tell user there's no internet or data failed
                 }
             }];


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{



            });
        });   

    }
```

After a while, I have detected that the compiler cursor only arrives at the line:

```
  NSLog(@"PROCEDENCIA DESDE INTERNET %@", [array objectAtIndex:0]);
```

if the array has at least two objects. And normally the query result should only get one object.
Later it won't be possible to get two objects, only one will result from the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code is overly complex. There's no need for that first dispatch_async if you're using sendAsynchronousRequest. Also, since the completion handler is called on the main queue, there's no need for the other dispatch_async calls either. Try it without those, and see if that helps.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    NSLog(@"annotation taped TITLE %@",[[view annotation] title  ]);
    NSMutableString *ms = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://mujercanariasigloxxi.appgestion.eu/app_php_files/comprobartipo.php?id="];
    NSString *tipo=[[view annotation] title];
    [ms appendString:tipo];
    NSLog(@"TIPO ES AQUI %@", tipo);
    NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ms]];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request1 queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data1, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (data1) {
            NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:0 error:nil];
            NSLog(@"PROCEDENCIA DESDE INTERNET %@", [array objectAtIndex:0]);

        }else{
            // Tell user there's no internet or data failed
        }
    }];
}
```

After Edit:

This is the actual code that I used in my test. See if it works for you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableString *ms = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://mujercanariasigloxxi.appgestion.eu/app_php_files/comprobartipo.php?id="];
    NSString *tipo=@"ORIFLAME";
    NSString *tipo2 = @"centro1";
    [ms appendString:tipo];
    //[ms appendString:tipo2];
    NSLog(@"TIPO ES AQUI %@", tipo);
    NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ms]];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request1 queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data1, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (data1) {
            NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:0 error:nil];
            NSLog(@"PROCEDENCIA DESDE INTERNET %@", array);

        }else{
            NSLog(@"no data");
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try your proposal when I find where is the error on it, for now Xcode is throwing an 'expected expression' error ???

Comment: @mvasco, sorry, I missed a closing bracket and semicolon (after the second to last "}"). I've updated.

Comment: Please, no need to say sorry. Your code is better than mine, no doubt about it, but the problem is still there. Only if the resulting array has more than one object, the last NSLog is called as expected, but if the array has only one object, as it should be, the last NSLog is not called. Any clue about it?

Comment: @mvasco, Is the app crashing before it reaches that log?

Comment: No, no crash, if the array has only one object, the last NSLog showed is NSLog(@"TIPO ES AQUI %@", tipo); and nothing else happens. I can continue working with the app...

Comment: @mvasco, then you should put a log in the "else" clause -- it must be going into it instead of the "if" part. If that's what' happening, then the problem is in your server code, not the iOS part.

Comment: I have put a log in the else clause, and you are right. If the array has only one object, the log in the else clause is shown. But I don't understand the issue, I can execute the server code on a web browser and there is not error shown. You can check it if you want.

Comment: this URL shows an array with one object: http://mujercanariasigloxxi.appgestion.eu/app_php_files/comprobartipo.php?id=ORIFLAME

Comment: and this one an array with two objects: http://mujercanariasigloxxi.appgestion.eu/app_php_files/comprobartipo.php?id=centro1

Comment: @mvasco. I just tested your two strings in my Xcode app, and they both worked fine. The response wasn't real fast, maybe 10 seconds before I got the values.

Comment: and what should I do now? in my Xcode app it only works when there are the two objects

Comment: @mvasco, are you sure that [[view annotation] title] is returning the strings you posted in your last comment? In my test, I hard coded those values (since I don't have an annotation), and that worked.

Comment: Yes, I am sure, I will put the logs here: TIPO ES AQUI ORIFLAME 
2014-03-21 23:38:53.070 Vive Gran Canaria[1473:60b] ESTO ES DATA en ELSE (null)
2014-03-21 23:38:53.071 Vive Gran Canaria[1473:60b] NO HAY CONEXION

Comment: @mvasco, I added the code I actually used to run my test of your code.

Comment: and here is the log for the to objects array: TIPO ES AQUI centro1
2014-03-21 23:39:44.025 Vive Gran Canaria[1473:60b] PROCEDENCIA DESDE INTERNET 2
2014-03-21 23:39:44.026 Vive Gran Canaria[1473:60b] ESTO ES DATA en If <5b223222 2c223222 5d>

Comment: It is working hard coding the values, but I still don't understand the problem when getting the values from the NSString.

Comment: You can see at the above logs that the strings are the same as when hard coded.

Comment: @mvasco, The only other thing I can think of is to check the length of the strings to make sure they don't contain any non-printable characters that wouldn't show up in your logs.

Comment: Ok, I will try it....you have been very nice to me, I really appreciate your time and patience.

Comment: I have found the problem, you were right, there are strings in the database with an extra blank space at the end. After removing all blank spaces at the end of all strings, the code is working fine. Thank you again.